# Usb permissions

Tags: usb

I can only get output from a connected usb robot arm when I run my Python script in sudo. I assume I need to give normal user permission for the usb device. How would I do this?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582398/5219609